# cmds.move issue Maya GUI (PYTHON)

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def shapeTool ():
    ram = 'RenamerWin'
    if cmds.window(ram, q = True, exists =True):
        cmds.deleteUI(ram)

    ram = cmds.window("RenamerWin",t = "Shape Tool", w=300, h=300)
    cmds.columnLayout(adj = True)
    cmds.separator(h=20)
    cmds.text("Welcome to the Shape Creator")
    cmds.separator(h=20)


    cubW = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Width", min =0, max = 10, field = True)
    cubH = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Height", min =0, max = 10, field = True)
    cubD = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Depth", min =0, max = 10, field = True)

    cubX = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Translate X axis", field = True)
    cubY = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Translate Y axis", field = True)
    cubZ = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Translate Z axis", field = True)

    def myCube(_):
        myCubeWidth = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubW , q= True,value =True)
        myCubeHeight = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubH , q= True,value =True) 
        myCubeDepth = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubD , q= True,value =True)
        myCubeMoveX = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubMX , q= True,value =True)
        myCubeMoveY = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubMY , q= True,value =True)
        myCubeMoveZ = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubMZ , q= True,value =True)
        cmds.polyCube(w=myCubeWidth,h=myCubeHeight,d=myCubeDepth , n = "myCube")
        cmds.move(myCubeMoveX, x=True )
        cmds.move(myCubeMoveY, x=True )
        cmds.move(myCubeMoveZ, x=True )

    cmds.button(l = "Create a Cube",c=myCube)

    cmds.showWindow(ram)

shapeTool()
```

Hi there,

I dont uderstand why this isnt working... When I comment out Move, then the GUI works so it must be to do with that. 
If anyone has any ideas please let me know

Thanks.

Comment: you should inlcude the error in your description for people to help more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you want to move in all three direction then you need pass xyz=True and you had a typo also  not cubMX just cubX ?.. Here is a slight modified version which is working

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def shapeTool ():
    ram = 'RenamerWin'
    if cmds.window(ram, q = True, exists =True):
        cmds.deleteUI(ram)

    ram = cmds.window("RenamerWin",t = "Shape Tool", w=300, h=300)
    cmds.columnLayout(adj = True)
    cmds.separator(h=20)
    cmds.text("Welcome to the Shape Creator")
    cmds.separator(h=20)


    cubW = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Width", min =0, max = 10, field = True)
    cubH = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Height", min =0, max = 10, field = True)
    cubD = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Depth", min =0, max = 10, field = True)

    cubX = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Translate X axis", field = True)
    cubY = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Translate Y axis", field = True)
    cubZ = cmds.intSliderGrp(l = "Translate Z axis", field = True)

    def myCube(_):
        myCubeWidth = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubW , q= True,value =True)
        myCubeHeight = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubH , q= True,value =True) 
        myCubeDepth = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubD , q= True,value =True)
        myCubeMoveX = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubX , q= True,value =True)
        myCubeMoveY = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubY , q= True,value =True)
        myCubeMoveZ = cmds.intSliderGrp(cubZ , q= True,value =True)
        print myCubeMoveZ, myCubeMoveY, myCubeMoveX
        cmds.polyCube(w=myCubeWidth,h=myCubeHeight,d=myCubeDepth , n = "myCube")
        cmds.move(myCubeMoveX,myCubeMoveY,myCubeMoveZ,  xyz=True )

    cmds.button(l = "Create a Cube",c=myCube)

    cmds.showWindow(ram)

shapeTool()
```